# Nested Assembly Loop produces unexpected output

Tags: assembly, x86

I am trying to build a nested loop in assembly. This is the code I am trying to convert.

```
int total = 0 ;
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
     for (j = 1; j<=5; j++)
     {
          total = total + i*j;
          System.out.println(total);
     }
}
```

The output is not what I expect at all. The code seems like it should work.

```
3892
3910
3922
3928
3953
3972
3988
4003
4032
```

My code

```
%include "io.mac"
.STACK 100H 
.DATA

  total  db 0

   .CODE
        .STARTUP

    mov  ECX,10 ; set outer loop count
L1:             ; begin the outer loop

    push ECX ; save outer loop count

    mov ECX, 5 ; set inner loop count

L2:
    mov ax, bx ;move saved outer loop count into ax to be multiplied by cx
    mul CX  ;multiply inner loop count by outloop count

    add [total], AX  ;add ecx to the total
    nwln
    PutInt [total]   ; print answer
    loop L2 ; repeat inner loop


    pop ECX ;restore outer loop
    mov BX, CX ;move outer loop count into EAX
    loop L1 ;repeat outer loop

        .EXIT
```

Comment: Can you please add the expected and the wrong behavior to make it more clear. Unless it is very difficult to solve the problem for others.

Comment: `mov BX, CX ;move outer loop count into EAX` wat

Comment: Have you tried debugging by stepping through the code instruction by instruction?

Comment: You move a garbage bx into ax first time through.

Comment: One byte ( [total] ) is not big enough for the answer.

Comment: That's what was wrong. I didn't catch that.